# how to install pytorch on ubuntu 16.04lts?

Tags: 16.04, python

i tried to install pytorch on ubuntu 16.04 everything running fine but when i activate pytorch_awesome and put python for import torch so it shows error (pytorch-awesome) linux@ubuntu:~/pytorch_awesome$ python

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul 17 2020, 14:04:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'torch'
```

how i put import torch and how i succesfully installed pytorch and check it is installed or not?

Comment: May be you are using pip to install it. Pip does it in python2. You should try to use pip3 to install it.

Comment: I am sorry I could not understand your question very well, how did you install pytorch? Is pytorch_awesome a virtual environment of some kind? At any rate my experience is using conda for installing pytorch was the easiest way.